# Display Html tags in IR from a function

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a function and inside it , I write a case to display an `img` tag as we see :

```
 FUNCTION HTML_SAMPLE (...)
....
BEGIN

SELECT 
CASE "ISACTIVE"
             WHEN 1 THEN
              '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#ok-icon.png" />'
             WHEN 0 THEN
              '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Button-no-icon.png" />'
           END "ISACTIVE_ICON"
FROM PERSONS;
....
END;
```

and here when I use it for an **interactive report** , it wont display html tags correctly ! Even I set the `escape special characters` **off**
[image]

and there's a strange thing to know ! when I use the table from function directly in IR , it will work correctly ! and the source of img will be different !

here's what I've selected directly in IR :

```
 SELECT 
    CASE "ISACTIVE"
                 WHEN 1 THEN
                  '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#ok-icon.png" />'
                 WHEN 0 THEN
                  '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Button-no-icon.png" />'
               END "ISACTIVE_ICON"
    FROM PERSONS;
```

[image]

How could this happen ? I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason (I don't know why), function should return only image name, without HTML tags or image location.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_is_clerk (par_empno IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   retval  VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT CASE
             WHEN job = 'CLERK' THEN 
                  'CB_CHECKED.JPG' 
                  -- Not this! '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#CB_CHECKED.JPG"/>'
          END
     INTO retval
     FROM emp
    WHERE empno = par_empno;

   RETURN retval;
END;
/
```

Interactive Report query should be adjusted so that it concatenates starting part of HTML tags and image location with function result and ending HTML part:

```
  SELECT ename,
         job,
         CASE WHEN job = 'CLERK' THEN '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#CB_CHECKED.JPG"/>' END is_clerk,
         --       
         '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#' || f_is_clerk (empno) || '"/>' is_clerk_fnc
    FROM emp
   WHERE deptno = 10
ORDER BY ename;
```

Then IR shows the image as expected:

[image]

---

If function returns *everything* (as in your case):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN job = 'CLERK' THEN '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#CB_CHECKED.JPG"/>' END
INTO retval
```

and IR query contains just

```
f_is_clerk (empno) is_clerk_fnc
```

result is as yours: wrong:

[image]

Therefore, do as instructed. Hopefully, someone else will be able to explain why it happens; I can't.

Comment: Since you've tested it, I wonder if it would parse correctly if the function f_is_clerk would have a in parameter "p_images_dir". That way the substitution string #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# is part of the select statement and it could be substituted before it is sent to the function